# How to use the default variable for only one of a few variables in less

Tags: variables, less

Here is my mixin

```
.test(@color:black; @width:100px; @height:50px) {
    width:@width; 
    height:@height; 
    background:@color;
    }
```

Here is where it's called later

```
 .mydiv {.test('use-mixin-color'; 300px; 150px);}
```

How can I override the size of .mydiv, while using the color defined in the mixin?
Everything I have tried overrides the mixin color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Use mixin in LESS, pass those parameter to override mixin default value :

**Soluations :**

```
.test(@color:black; @width:100px; @height:50px) {
    width : @width; 
    height : @height; 
    background : @color;
 }

.mydiv {
    .test(@width : 300px; @height : 150px);
 }
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
 .mydiv {
   width: 300px;
   height: 150px;
   background: black;
 }
```

Helpful :)

Comment: Perfect, I knew it would be something simple! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer. There're multiple methods (actually infinite) but if you want your mixin to be most easy *for use* you can provide a ["specialization"](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-pattern-matching) for a specific argument value or number of arguments. Like this for example:

```less
// usage:

.foo {.test(red, 1px, 2px)}
.bar {.test(3px, 4px)}

// impl.:

.test(@color, @width, @height) {
    width: @width; 
    height: @height; 
    background: @color;
}

.test(@width, @height) { // <- "no color" specialization
    .test(black, @width, @height);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%2F%2F%20usage%3A%5Cn%5Cn.foo%20%7B.test(red%2C%201px%2C%202px)%7D%5Cn.bar%20%7B.test(3px%2C%204px)%7D%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20impl.%3A%5Cn%5Cn.test(%40color%2C%20%40width%2C%20%40height)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20width%3A%20%40width%3B%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20height%3A%20%40height%3B%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20background%3A%20%40color%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.test(%40width%2C%20%40height)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.test(black%2C%20%40width%2C%20%40height)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D).

---

Also think twice before adding default parameter values for a mixin like:

```less
.test(@color: black, @width: 100px, @height: 50px) { ...
```

People tend to overuse this feature while it's rarely really necessary (and only creates an extra code-noise) except some specific use-cases.
I.e. consider if you actually expect your mixin to be invoked as:

```less
test;
test(blue, 4em);
// etc.
```

Do you?
It's usually a good idea to start without default parameter values (at least to protect the mixin against accidental misuse), i.e.:

```less
.test(@color, @width, @height) { ...
```

and add them later *only* where and when they are necessary.